# Profiting from Palestinian businesses that harm Jews

Tags: halacha, money

Many Orthodox men in Israel (who are relatively poor and frequently save on car insurance) fix their cars in Palestinian garages over the border. Prices can be ridiculously low relative to Israeli garages that use authorized parts and pay taxes. On the other hand, Palestinians are known for stealing and disassembling Israeli cars for parts (in 30 years I personally had 3 cars stolen and 2 attempts to steal, the 3 cars were located by the insurance over the fence). Even if the car is insured it's always a loss of thousands of Shekels.

What are Halachic guidlines (with sources) about a situation where fixing a car can save a couple of thousands of Shekels, whith a high probability that another Jew was indirectly harmed in the process?

*NB: taking vehicles to garages over the border is forbidden by the Israeli law.*

Comment: This seems like 2 separate issues. Unless you are implying that literally every garage in the Palestinian side steals the cars brought in by Israelis to be worked on. It seems like there are garages, and there are thieves, and those thieves may sometimes take those cars to garages to strip parts or do things.

Comment: relevant: https://daat.ac.il/he-il/toshba/shulchan_aruch/choshen-mishpat/gneva/siman356.htm

Comment: If there's indeed a legitimate case that the majority of Palestinian garages use stolen Israeli parts then it's like any other case of illicitly saving money at the expense of another Jew. But beyond "people say", how would you establish that is the case?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a garage that doesn't pay taxes, regardless of the rest?

Comment: @Heshy I was talking about the Palestinian garages. But, yes, if he does it for cash, leave the car by the garage and he tells you that he'll fix it in his after-hours. And not everybody (esp here in Israel) follows R' Moshe.